# Mostrar por pantalla con jQuery un array

Tags: jquery

El array esta creado en php, ¿esto puede influir?
Mostrar por pantalla con jQuery un array que por consola se muestra así

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Si pongo `$(".info").text(id_event[0]);` me muestra una A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haz un parse

```
var datos = [1,2,3,4,5];
alert(datos.toString());
```

Dime si te vale ;)

Comment: Si hago lo que me has pasado me imprime 1,2,3,4,5 pero cambio tu array por el mio e imprime `Array ( [0] => 1 )`. El array esta creado en php, ¿esto puede influir?

Comment: depende, lo estas creando en php y lo pasas con ```json.encode```?

Comment: Ahora sí. Pero vaya que me es indiferente. Como vaya mejor. Me da igual hacerlo de una forma o otra.

Comment: Esto te lo digo, por que si lo estas haciendo para que te devuelva en formato array, Puedes hacer 2 cosas: 1 ```dataType: JSON``` o 2 hacer un ```JSON.parse()```